# Gronwall's lemma

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Suppose that $F:\mathbb{R}^{1+d}\to \mathbb{R}^d$ continuous and there is $g:[0,\infty)\to \mathbb{R}$ continuous that $\|F(t,x)\|\leq g(\|x\|)$ and $\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{dr}{g(r)}=\infty$. Prove that all maximum solution of $x'=F(t,x)$, $x(t_0)=0$ are definite for all $t>t_0$.

So, i tried to suppose for contradiction that there is a $\tilde{x}:I\to \mathbb{R}^{1+d}$ that $\tilde{x}(t_0)=0$ isn't definite in $\tilde{t}\in (t_0,\infty)$. Applying Gronwall in $\frac{1}{\|F(\tilde{x}(t))\|}$ in $[t_0,\tilde{t})$, thought that i could find a constant that:

$$C>\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\|F(\tilde{x}(t))\|}dt \geq \int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{g(\|\tilde{x}(t)\|)}dt = \infty$$

but i couldn't. Somebody can help me? :) thanks

Comment: What do you mean $\frac{dr}{g(r)}$?

Comment: i wrote twice.. edited! :)